# how to implement selection of date range in iOS?

Tags: ios, swift, iphone, xcode

Has anyone implemented the calendar control in iOS which facilitate selection of date range?
I am developing a app which require selection of date in range.If any body has implemented. Please suggest. also attached reference image.
[image]

Answer (score 6):

You can use DSLCalendarView.

https://www.cocoacontrols.com/controls/dslcalendarview

It is simple and easy to use.

Answer (score 4):

You can check [this component](https://github.com/kovpas/PMCalendar), it has the facility of selection of date range. This is one other [resourceful link](https://www.cocoacontrols.com/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=calendar) for finding open source controls.